# Method (with optional parameter) mocked with mockito return null on unit test. Dart Flutter

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, dart, stream, mockito

Im five hours trying solve it, doesn't work nothing. I wanna test bloc class that use stream and sink data after load data from internet. The use case test work well but the bloc class was a huge headache today, this already work on app, but the test I really dont know how to solve

file bloc.dart

```
class Bloc {
  final UseCase _useCase;
  Bloc(this._useCase);

  final _controller = StreamController.broadcast();

  Stream get stream => _controller.stream;

  doSomething() async {
    ResponseModel responseModel = await _useCase.call();
    _controller.sink.add(responseModel);//<-- I would like test this
  }

  dispose() {
    _controller.close();
  }
}
```

This is the unit test class bloc_test.dart

```
class UseCaseMock extends Mock implements UseCase {}

main() {
  UseCase useCase;
  Bloc bloc;
  setUp(() async {
    useCase = UseCaseMock();
    bloc = Bloc(useCase);
  });

  tearDown(() {
    bloc.dispose();
  });

  group('Test Bloc', () {
    test('load stuff must sink Response ', () async {
      when(useCase.call())
          .thenAnswer((_) async => ResponseModel('id','name'));
          
       //FIRST I TRY It, DOESNT WORK   
      // await expectLater( bloc.stream, emits(isA<ResponseModel>()));


      bloc.stream.listen((response) {
      
        //print(response) <-----return null  I THINK HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        expect(response, isA<ResponseModel>());
      });

      await bloc.doSomething();
    });
  });
}
```

Please, would you know how to solve it? Thanks

[Solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64011071/2767337)

Comment: You defined a class "MyBloc" but in the test you are using a class "Bloc". Is that a typo?

Comment: What are you getting as output from this test? Also, did you mean to `await bloc.loadStuff()`?

Comment: @Abion47 I would like that listen into a test receive what I send by sink.add into bloc. I chance little bit the old code to be more understandable.

Comment: @Victor Eronmosele  I rewrite thus was a pseudocode of my app.

Comment: Alright. I'll post my answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Solved! my usecase has a method "call" with an **optional parameter**

```
 Future<ResponseModel> call( {String value });
```

I was mocking wrong as below

```
 when(useCase.call()) <----------------here is the error
          .thenAnswer((_) async => ResponseModel('id','name'));
```

Inside true Bloc class(not a pseudocode that I had posted) I execute a usecase using the parameter

```
// this is the true doSomething() method on my app
loadCoupons(String storeId) async {
    final result = await searchCouponUseCase(storeId: storeId);
    _controller.sink.add(result);
  }
```

***And the solution is:***
Mock using optional parameter(if it will be called)! I was testing without parameter because when putting  "any" inside the test like a   when( useCase.call( **any**))... not compile.

```
 when(useCase.call(   value: ''    )) <-----solved
          .thenAnswer((_) async => ResponseModel('id','name'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run your async operation before using `expectLater` for assertion. Also remove the `await` from `bloc.doSomething()` as it times out otherwise.

This will work.

```
test('load stuff must sink Response ', () async {
    when(useCase.call())
        .thenAnswer((_) async => ResponseModel('id','name'));
    bloc.doSomething();

    await expectLater(bloc.stream, emits(isA<Response>()));
  });
```

Comment: your code works! I thank you, but the true problem is another https://stackoverflow.com/a/64011071/2767337